# How can I control program flow using events and promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp, promise, ecmascript-6

I have a class like so:

```
import net from 'net';
import {EventEmitter} from 'events';
import Promise from 'bluebird';

class MyClass extends EventEmitter {
    constructor(host = 'localhost', port = 10011) {
        super(EventEmitter);
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
        this.socket = null;
        this.connect();
    }
    connect() {
        this.socket = net.connect(this.port, this.host);
        this.socket.on('connect', this.handle.bind(this));
    }
    handle(data) {
        this.socket.on('data', data => {

        });
    }
    send(data) {
        this.socket.write(data);
    }
}
```

How would I turn the `send` method into a promise, which returns a value from the socket's `data` event? The server only sends data back when data is sent to it, other than a connection message which can easily be suppressed.

I've tried something like:

```
handle(data) {
    this.socket.on('data', data => {
        return this.socket.resolve(data);
    });
    this.socket.on('error', this.socket.reject.bind(this));
}
send(data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.socket.resolve = resolve;
        this.socket.reject = reject;
        this.socket.write(data);
    });
}
```

Obviously this won't work because `resolve`/`reject` will overwrite each other when chaining and/or calling `send` multiple times in parallel.

There's also the problem of calling `send` twice in parallel and it resolving whichever response comes back first.

I currently have an implementation using a queue and defers , but it feels messy since the queue is constantly being checked.

I'd like to be able to do the following:

```
let c = new MyClass('localhost', 10011);
c.send('foo').then(response => {
    return c.send('bar', response.param);
    //`response` should be the data returned from `this.socket.on('data')`.
}).then(response => {
    console.log(response);
}).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Just to add, I don't have any control over the data that is received, meaning it can't be modified outside of the stream.

**Edit**: So it seems this is pretty impossible, due to TCP not having a request-response flow. How can this be implemented still using promises, but either using a single-execution (one request at a time) promise chain or a queue.

Comment: You mean like a two-way chat? Send one message and wait till you get one message, like that?

Comment: @thefourtheye Almost, except I may need to call `send` in parallel and the promise should return the correct response depending on what was sent. Though all the received data comes from one stream so it's not exactly traceable.

Comment: I'm guessing here ... could you set up some kind of observer object in `socket` with an `.add()` method, then call `this.socket.observer.add({
   reject: reject,
   resolve: resolve
  };` from `send()`?

Comment: You mean like Q-Connection?

Comment: Also - is the server cooperating?

Comment: In your described method (the one you've tried), overwriting is not a problem when chaining since you only call `send` the second time inside the `then` handler (that is, after the first promise is resolved). Regarding parallel `send`s, that's not possible regardless of language/code structure because the problem is in the protocol definition. If you want a serial request/response communication protocol (that is, without correlated message id), you have to obey the rules and wait for a response before sending the next request.

Comment: So **just-boris**'s answer is not an option for you? Do you want to process your messages one by one or allow multiple messages in an _open_ state?  Do responses come back in the same order in which the corresponding requests were sent?

Comment: @arturgrzesiak Just-boris's answer isn't an option, since I can't control what data comes back so I can't give it an ID. I can't allow messages in an open state since there's no way to identify and correspond the request to the response. As far as I know the requests are processed sequentially. But let's just say they aren't. In which case, I only want the class to allow one request at a time, adding it to a queue if one is already being processed. When the processed response is complete, I want it to resolve the request promise and then send the next and so on.

Comment: @BenFortune haven't we already worked this out in chat?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Yeah sorry. You said it could be done with promises and chaining but I wasn't quite sure how the implementation would look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I distilled the problem to the bare minimum and made it browser runnable:

1. Socket class is mocked.
2. Removed info about port, host and inheritance from `EventEmitter`.

The solution works by appending new requests to the promise chain, but allowing maximum one open / not-answered request at any given timepoint. `.send` returns a new promise each time it is called and the class takes care of all internal synchronisation. So, `.send` may be called multiple times and the correct ordered (FIFO) of requests processing is guaranteed. One additional feature that I added is trimming the promise chain, if there are no pending requests.

---

**Caveat** I omitted error handling altogether, butit should be tailored to your particular use case anyway.

---

[**DEMO**](http://www.es6fiddle.net/ichu6qur/)

```
class SocketMock {

  constructor(){
    this.connected = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve,200) ); 
    this.listeners = {
  //  'error' : [],
    'data' : []
    }
  }

  send(data){

    console.log(`SENDING DATA: ${data}`);
    var response = `SERVER RESPONSE TO: ${data}`;
    setTimeout( () => this.listeners['data'].forEach(cb => cb(response)),               
               Math.random()*2000 + 250); 
  }

  on(event, callback){
    this.listeners[event].push(callback); 
  }

}

class SingleRequestCoordinator {

    constructor() {
        this._openRequests = 0; 
        this.socket = new SocketMock();
        this._promiseChain = this.socket
            .connected.then( () => console.log('SOCKET CONNECTED'));
      this.socket.on('data', (data) => {
        this._openRequests -= 1;
        console.log(this._openRequests);
        if(this._openRequests === 0){
          console.log('NO PENDING REQUEST --- trimming the chain');
          this._promiseChain = this.socket.connected
        }
        this._deferred.resolve(data);
      });

    }

    send(data) {
      this._openRequests += 1;
      this._promiseChain = this._promiseChain
        .then(() => {
            this._deferred = Promise.defer();
            this.socket.send(data);
            return this._deferred.promise;
        });
      return this._promiseChain;
    }
}

var sender = new SingleRequestCoordinator();

sender.send('data-1').then(data => console.log(`GOT DATA FROM SERVER --- ${data}`));
sender.send('data-2').then(data => console.log(`GOT DATA FROM SERVER --- ${data}`));
sender.send('data-3').then(data => console.log(`GOT DATA FROM SERVER --- ${data}`));

setTimeout(() => sender.send('data-4')
    .then(data => console.log(`GOT DATA FROM SERVER --- ${data}`)), 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `send()` calls is messed with each other, you should save it into cache. To be sure that received message matches with sent you should assign some unique `id` for each message into payload.

So your message sender will look like this

```
class MyClass extends EventEmitter {
  constructor() {
    // [redacted]
    this.messages = new Map();
  }

  handle(data) {
    this.socket.on('data', data => {
       this.messages.get(data.id)(data);
       this.messages.delete(data.id);
    });
  }

  send(data) {
    return return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.messages.set(data.id, resolve);
        this.socket.write(data);
    });
  }
}
```

This code will not be sensible to message order and you will get API, that you want.

Comment: There's no way to assign an `id` outside of the script. The `id` won't be returned from the stream meaning the script won't know which response has been received.

Comment: So, you want to resolve promise with any next data frame from socket? This solution doesn't seem reliable, but you can do it, if you make `messages` array instead of object

Answer (score 0):

`socket.write(data[, encoding][, callback])` takes a callback. You can reject or resolve in this callback.

```
class MyClass extends EventEmitter {
  constructor(host = 'localhost', port = 10011) {
    super(EventEmitter);
    this.host = host;
    this.port = port;
    this.socket = null;
    this.requests = null;
    this.connect();
  }
  connect() {
    this.socket = net.connect(this.port, this.host);
    this.socket.on('connect', () => {
      this.requests = [];
      this.socket.on('data', this.handle.bind(this));
      this.socket.on('error', this.error.bind(this));
    });
  }
  handle(data) {
    var [request, resolve, reject] = this.requests.pop();
    // I'm not sure what will happen with the destructuring if requests is empty
    if(resolve) {
      resolve(data);
    }
  }
  error(error) {
    var [request, resolve, reject] = this.requests.pop();
    if(reject) {
      reject(error);
    }
  }
  send(data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if(this.requests === null) {
        return reject('Not connected');
      }
      this.requests.push([data, resolve, reject]);
      this.socket.write(data);
    });
  }
}
```

Not tested and therefore not sure about method signatures, but that's the basic idea.

This assumes that there will be one `handle` or `error` event per request made.

The more I think about it, this seems impossible without additional information in your application data, like packet numbers to match a response to a request.

The way it's implemented now (and also the way it is in your question), it's not even sure that one answer will match exactly one `handle` event.

Comment: The callback is only to check if the data was sent, I want to resolve the promise when the data is received. The only received data comes from the `data` event.

Comment: Then you're out of luck with a Promise. The point is to run it only once. The Promise is to do it whether it already happened or whether it might happen in the future...

Comment: But the promise will only be resolved once. Basically I want the flow to be `send -> create promise -> return promise -> receive data -> resolve promise`.

Comment: Yes, like I said, it will only resolve once, that's the point of a Promise. Your use case isn't a good one to use Promises.